# Object.isEmpty vs .isEmpty() vs _.isEmpty(Object) javascript, lodash, underscore

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, lodash

```
var foo = { bar: ''};
```

Often I have seen code like this:

```
    if(foo.bar.isEmpty()){ //this line most of the time breaks
        // do something
    }


    foo.bar.isEmpty() or foo.bar.isEmpty
```

As far as I know, this is not native JavaScript/jQuery. Even if Lodash and Underscore are included in the project this doesn't seem to work.

There are implementations of `isEmpty()` in Lodash and Underscore
but the only way to use them is `_.isEmpty(foo.bar)`

Why can't I use them as `foo.bar.isEmpty()?`

What is the correct way to check for empty array, object or string?

Comment: Part of the [lodash/underscore philosophy is not to extend any prototypes](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-native-builtins/) and instead expose everything on the `_` namespace. Thus these libraries will never expose their functionality on `foo.bar.isEmpty`

Comment: so using foo.bar.isEmpty is incorrect!.

Answer (score 2):

As soon as `foo.bar` (or `foo`) is `undefined` and you have chained another function, for example `isEmpty()` after it, your script will break because `undefined` doesn't have a method `isEmpty()`.

To securely check if an object property's value holds an empty string in plain js, you need to use

```
if (foo && foo.bar && foo.bar !== '')
```

Comment: well the empty string "" is just an example what if the field is populated by server code be emtpy {} or emtpy [], and for that you probably need something as _.isEmpty()